# Supabase after login session does not save in local storage and does not get authenticated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, backend, supabase

Im currently having an issue where after a the supabase login function occurs, it makes two reads to the database to check if the user exists in either the client or the trainer table. At the moment I have noticed that after the login the user is not authenticated and does not pass my RLS which describes only authenticated users for read access.

this is my login function`

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      event.preventDefault();

      // Validate form data
      const validationErrors = {};

      if (!formData.email.trim()) {
        validationErrors.email = "Email is required";
      } else if (!/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(formData.email)) {
        validationErrors.email = "Invalid email address";
      }

      if (!formData.password.trim()) {
        validationErrors.password = "Password is required";
      }

      // If there are validation errors, update the state and return
      if (Object.keys(validationErrors).length > 0) {
        setErrors(validationErrors);
        setIsLoading(false);
        return;
      } else {
        setErrors({});
      }

      // Login user
      let loginUser = await login(formData.email, formData.password);
      if (loginUser.error) throw new Error(loginUser.error.message);
      let userId = loginUser.data.user.id;

      // Check if user exists in trainer table
      const isTrainer = await getTrainer(userId);
      if (isTrainer.error) throw new Error(isTrainer.error.message);

      // Check if user exists in client table
      const isClient = await getClient(userId);
      if (isClient.error) throw new Error(isClient.error.message);

      if (isClient.data.length === 0 && isTrainer.data.length === 0) throw new Error("User not found");
      else toastsuccess("Logged In!");

      if (isTrainer.data.length > 0) navigate("/trainer-dashboard");
      if (isClient.data.length > 0) navigate("/client-dashboard");
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      toasterror(error.message);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

This is my exported functions, they are in different files as I want to keep the business logic for the backend independent

```
export async function login(email, password) {
  return await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({ email, password });
}


export async function getClient(clientId) {
  return await supabase.from("clients").select().eq("clientId", clientId);
}

export async function getTrainer(trainerId) {
  return await supabase.from("trainers").select().eq("trainerId", trainerId);
}
```

lastly as it might be useful I have my Auth context

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [role, setRole] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Get the role of the session
    async function fetchRole(userId) {
      console.log(userId);
      const trainer = await getTrainer(userId);
      if (trainer.data.length > 0) {
        setRole("trainer");
      }
      const client = await getClient(userId);
      if (client.data.length > 0) {
        setRole("client");
      }
    }

    // Get current session function
    async function getSession() {
      const { session, error } = await currentSession();
      if (session) {
        setUser(session?.user ?? null);
        fetchRole(session?.user?.id);
      } else if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    }

    getSession();

    // Detect the user's auth state
    const { data } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event, session) => {
      setUser(session?.user ?? null);
      if (session) {
        await fetchRole(session?.user?.id);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => {
      data?.subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const value = {
    user,
    role,
    loading,
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{!loading && children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}
```

My RLS Policies for both tables are set to "ALL(READ, WRITE etc)" for only authenticated users, when I have it set to anon users it works just fine but I do not want this

Comment: So you are seeing a `User not found` error when `handleSubmit` gets called, correct? Can you try to call `supabase.auth.getSession()`, store the return value in a variable, and see if there is an active session right after you sign in?